# plotting multiple plots in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, legend

I am trying to plot a signal which has been filtered with different filters in 1 plot. The only problem is i have to plot the raw signal once and the different filtered signal upon it. handling the color and the legend is getting a mess.

```
label{1} = 'raw_Signal'
for i = 1:NumOfFilter
    f = FilterClass();
    f.fc = x;  % fc changes for each filter
    for j = 1: length(Signal) % every signal will have multiple segments
         filtered_signal = f.eval(signal(j).seg)
         plot(handles.axes2, signal(j).time,signal(j).seg,signal(j).time,filtered_signal)
         hold(handles.axes2,'on')
    end
label{i+1} = 'filter_1'
end
```

So `signal(j).seg` is a part of my raw signal and `filtered_signal` filtered signal of `signal(j).seg`. I need to plot original signal only once and the filtered signal multiple times over that. how do i do this without messing up the legend and color of the signal.

Comment: Sorry i did not mention it correctly, i did edit my question if you can look at it again

Comment: The term 'messing up' is very broad. Could you also include exactly what you want? Preferably with an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I read your question correct, you have a bunch of raw signal segments, and for each one of them you like to apply a set of different filters. By doing so you would like the legend to be something like

- Raw signal
- Filter1
- FIlter2
- ...

The problem with legend is that the order by default is the same as the plotting order, and as you also plots different segements for the same signal it adds to the mess.

There are different ways around this

1. Create and store all the signals in advance (in a separate for-loop). Then plot them in the order you want and the legend solves itself.
2. Store the plot handle and arrange them in the order you like by using `uistack` before setting the legend

The first option is cleaner. But if you choose the second option you should split the plotting of raw and filtered signals

```
rawH = plot(handles.axes2, signal(j).time,signal(j).seg)
filtH(i) = plot(handles.axes2,signal(j).time,filtered_signal, 'Color', FiltColor{i})
```

Here I only store the last handle, but I think that serves your purpose. 
You need to set `hold on` before that, or tell the axes to add plots

```
set(handles.axes2, 'NextPlot', 'add')
```

Then simply move the filterd signal handles to the top and above them the raw handle. Then plot the legend

```
uistack(filtH, 'top')
uistack(rawH, 'top')
legend(label)
```